# how to pass dynamic query URL to server - angular

Tags: angular

Here is the http-service -

```
  public getProducts(
    gender?: ProductGender,
    category?: ProductCategory,
  ): Observable<IGetProductsResponse> {
    const baseUrl = ENDPOINT;

      return this.http.get<IGetProductsResponse>(
        `${baseUrl}list?gender=${gender}&category=${category}`
      );
  }
```

If I'm sending the request like this, i get 0 as the value I'm not filling. for example -

`http://localhost:4200/product-list?gender=1`

I'll get the category value as 0.

How can i use the URL in a way that able to get only `gender` or `category`?.

Tried to change the URL to - `${baseUrl}list?gender=${gender}` and that is working but it is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a ternary parameter variable and inject that into your URL string.

```
const param = !!gender ? `gender=${gender}` : `category=${category}`;

return this.http.get<IGetProductsResponse>(`${baseUrl}list?${param}`);
```

Since `0` is falsy, you can just use double bangs to evaluate `gender`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `HttpParams` instead, to build the parameter list however you need, rather than passing them manually like in your code. You can try this and see how it works:

```
  public getProducts(
    gender?: ProductGender,
    category?: ProductCategory
  ): Observable<IGetProductsResponse> {
    const baseUrl = ENDPOINT;
    const params = new HttpParams();

    if (gender) {
      params.append('gender', gender);
    }

    if (category) {
      params.append('category', category);
    }

    return this.http.get<IGetProductsResponse>(`${baseUrl}list`, { params });
  }
```